# Python Ctime conversion

Tags: python, time

I'm having issues coverting a ctime string over to %Y-%m-%d format.

```
fileobject = "C:\\foo\\bar.txt"
filetime = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(fileobject))

print filetime
Wed Feb 03 11:02:38 2016
```

Now I just want to convert to YYYY-MM-DD. Any suggestions? I'm not having luck with traditional reformatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filetime` is a string. That means you can use [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse it.

```
cdt = time.strptime(filetime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

At this point, `cdt` is a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object and you can manipulate it as such.

```
>>> cdt
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=0, tm_min=37, tm_sec=9, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=326, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: if the input is a filename then you should [avoid unnecessary `ctime()` conversion and use the desired (YYYY-MM-DD) format directly instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35200259/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) with [`time.localtime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) rather than using `time.ctime`:

```
>>> print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime(os.path.getctime(fileobject)))
2015-10-20
```

I won't tell you the file I used so the output will differ.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid ["Yo-Yo code"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/260710/1985) and format the file time in the desired format directly *without* converting it to a string using `ctime()` first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from datetime import datetime

filename = r"C:\foo\bar.txt"
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
print(dt.date())
# -> 2016-02-03
```

---

If you've received `ctime()`-formated time string from an external source then you could parse this (`asctime()`) date/time format using [`email` stdlib package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate):

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate
>>> parsedate('Wed Feb 03 11:02:38 2016')[:3]
(2016, 2, 3)
>>> "%04d-%02d-%02d" % _
'2016-02-03'
```

In general, [use `datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert a string into datetime object. See [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466345/4279).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
time.strptime(string[, format])
```

to format the output

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strptime` and then `strftime`:

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.strptime(filetime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
2016-02-03
```